# Can't Create an Android Project in Eclipse with ADT 20

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to follow the official Android "Building Your First App" tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/index.html using ADT 20 and Eclipse Juno on Windows 7.  Downloading and installing the SDK seemed to go great, I've got all the Tools, Android 4.1, and the Extras installed.  I've also installed the Eclipse plugin via https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/, which seemed to go fine as well.  I configured the plugin and it found the 4.1 SDK.

I have trouble when I try to create an Android project though.  After I follow the wizard to create an Android Application Project, my project is completely empty save for the folder structure.  There is no reference to the android jar, no "Hello World" files, absolutely nothing.

I can add the android.jar manually and start typing up my own "Hello World", but I can't set the build target either.

I go to Project **Properties -> Android** and I get an error message that says

```
"The currently displayed page contains invalid values".
```

The properties page does open and I can check Android 4.1 as a build target, but when I try to save it gives me an error message that disappears too fast to read and then doesn't save.

I'm honestly not sure what I need to do to get a basic project up and running.  I didn't get any errors while I was installing the SDK and the plugin.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think Eclipse Juno is fully supported for Android development yet. Try installing Eclipse Indigo and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the Eclipse indigo or any version before Juno as it has many issues.
You can see the various bugs registered at this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=eclipse%20juno&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles).

Your problems should go away once u change the eclipse version.